# Is there a version of `patch` for Windows that outputs CRLF files?

Tags: windows, patch, newline

I am using `patch` from UnxUtils (on Windows), which works (my file patches fine) but the outputted file has LF instead of CRLF line endings. Is there an equivilent to `patch` which outputs using CRLF instead of LF?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, turns out I was looking for the `--binary` option.

```
patch -p0 --binary < my.cpp.diff
```

FYI, this works with patches generated from this command:

```
diff -ac --binary path\to\my.cpp path\to\my.cpp.mine > my.cpp.diff
```

Comment: Well, it seems this does not always work. When I apply patches with the `--binary` option, all I get is failed hunks on a file that can be patched just fine otherwise. Did you also come across such a problem? (TBH I'm very surprised that such a widely used tool has this sort of a shortcoming - wouldn't it be a lot better to detect and honour LF/CRLF?)